# MutableAcl.createAcl() with custom UserDetailsService

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am currently trying to implement Spring's ACLs into my existing application.
Sadly i am stuck at a specific point which seems to be caused by my UserDetailsService.

The problem/error is the following when i call the `createAcl()` function of the 
`MutableAcl` class like this:

```
public void addPermission(long objectId, Sid recipient, Permission permission, Class clazz) {
    MutableAcl acl;
    ObjectIdentity oid = new ObjectIdentityImpl(clazz.getCanonicalName(), objectId);

    try {
        acl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.readAclById(oid);
    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        acl = mutableAclService.createAcl(oid);
    }

    acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), permission, recipient, true);
    mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl);
}
```

Inside of this function a new `ObjectIdentity` is created, if this class instance does not yet have one. A new `PrincipalSid` is created from the current `Authentication` object for this purpose (saved inside the ACL_SID table). Like this:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
PrincipalSid sid = new PrincipalSid(auth);
this.createObjectIdentity(objectIdentity, sid);
```

The problem occurs when it tries to save the entry into the `ACL_SID` table which is defined as this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACL_SID (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  principal BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  sid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_UK_1 UNIQUE(sid,principal)
);
```

As you can see the `sid` is a VARCHAR with 100 characters. My custom User class contains a few properties which are mostly converted to a String representation, which causes the `PrincipalSid` to be longer than 100 characters. Now the first obvious solution would be to just change the `toString` method to only return the most essential values.
Still this seems kinda "hacky" to me. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sid` column in `ACL_SID` table should only contain the username, not the entire user object with its properties. To create a correct instance of `PrincipalSid`, make sure at least one of following is true:

- `auth.getPrincipal()` returns an instance of [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) interface.
- `auth.getPrincipal().toString()` returns the username.

Comment: Strange. My custom UserDetailsService should already return a UserDetails interface as i have overwritten the funtion: `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String name)`. When the `PrincipalSid` is created the value of auth.getPrincipal() is not an instance of `UserDetails`, but of `SystemUser` (my custom User Entity) and thus the `toString` method of this is called instead. What might be wrong here?

Comment: Nevermind. I found my problem. I returned a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with my custom class as `Principal` in my AuthenticationProvider. Thanks for the hint in the right direction!